# Getting svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for my custom Svn Gradle plugin

Tags: svn, groovy, gradle

I wrote a custom gradle plugin using groovy to do basic svn tasks like, Checkout, Clean, Tag etc. The groovy class calls the svn command line client to do these operations, It works fine when i run it on my windows system but the same plugin gives the following error when i run it on a linux system (Centos).

> svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for
>   '%22https://source.mycompany.net/svn/MyProject/trunk%22'

Am able to make the same calls to the command line client through the command prompt or shell script without any issues. So what is the difference with

Here is my code sample:

```
    String command =String.format("svn co -r %d  --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --          username %s --password %s --depth infinity \"%s\" \"%s\"",
                                          getRevision(),
                                          getUserName(),
                                          getUserPassword(),
                                          getSrcUrl(),
                                          getDir());

    Process svnProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(svnProcess.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(svnProcess.getErrorStream()));
    String statusOutputLine =""
    while ((statusOutputLine = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
    {
    logger.quiet(" " + statusOutputLine);
    }

    while (( statusOutputLine = stdError.readLine()) != null)
    {
    logger.error(statusOutputLine)
    throw new Exception(statusOutputLine)
    }
    logger.quiet("Successfully Checked out the work space")
```

i do have neon installed on the system

-bash-4.1$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486)
   compiled Jun 25 2011, 11:30:15

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

- ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.

  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
- ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.

  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
- ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.

  - handles 'file' scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems pretty clear, the URL you are passing is inside the single quotes.  Note how it has a leading and trailing `%22`.  `%22` is how `"` is encoded in URLs.

The problem is that you're assuming that your command will be run through a shell.  It will not.  So your quotes become literals passed to the command.  Instead any whitespace will be split into separate arguments for you without any respect to the quotes.

If you want to control the splitting of arguments you should generate a list instead of a single string.

This documentation is on point (in particularly the Gotchas section under Option 1):
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy